# How do I select a DOM element that has multiple classes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select a DOM element that has these classes:

```
mq-editable-field mq-math-mode mq-field
```

I have tried using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mq-editable-field mq-math-mode mq-focused')
```

This is not working, is there another document function I should be using? I am using vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `querySelector`  and  `querySelectorAll` for get multiple-element by classes

**querySelector method :** return the first element within the document which matches a specified CSS selector(s)

```
let firstElement= document.querySelector('.mq-editable-field.mq-math-mode.mq-focused');
```

**querySelectorAll() method :** method returns all the elements within the document which matches the specified CSS selector(s).

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mq-editable-field.mq-math-mode.mq-focused');
```

Comment: I think you would need querySelectorAll for that

Answer (score 1):

Use a query selector:

```
document.querySelector('.mq-editable-field.mq-math-mode.mq-focused')
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection which can have multiple elements, thus the parallel would be `document.querySelectorAll()`. But the OP does say *a* DOM element.